# awk - how to delete first column with field separator

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a csv file with data presented as follows

```
87540221|1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
87540258|1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
87549647|1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
```

I'm trying to save the first column to a new file (without field separator , and then delete the first column from the main csv file along with the first field separator.

Any ideas?

This is what I have tried so far

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$1="";sub("|,"")}1'
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: What about cut? `cut -d '|' -f 2-`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your original CSV file is named "orig.csv":

```
awk -F'|' '{print $1 > "newfile"; sub(/^[^|]+\|/,"")}1' orig.csv > tmp && mv tmp orig.csv
```

Comment: `awk` solution works x20 times faster than `cut`. Tested on 15Gb CSV file.

Answer (score 19):

This is simple with `cut`:

```
$ cut -d'|' -f1 infile
87540221
87540258
87549647

$ cut -d'|' -f2- infile
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
```

Just redirect into the file you want:

```
$ cut -d'|' -f1 infile > outfile1

$ cut -d'|' -f2- infile > outfile2 && mv outfile2 file
```

Answer (score 3):

GNU awk

```
awk '{$1="";$0=$0;$1=$1}1' FPAT='[^|]+' OFS='|'
```

Output

```
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
```

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @darw Sets `$1` null. `$0=$0` resplits the record, which now starts with a `|` (the OFS). FPAT doesn't match a null, so `$1` is now the (former) second field. `$1=$1` causes a rebuild of the output record, with `OFS='|'`. The trailing `{...}1` is a shorthand for print: It is the pattern of a second pattern-action pair, and is boolean "true". With no action, awk defaults to `{print}`. gawk recognises variable settings after the program text without needing a `-v`.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe is special regex symbol and sub function expectes you to pass a regex. Correct awk command should be this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} {$1=""; sub(/\|/, "")}'1 file
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
1356438283301|1356438284971|1356438292151697
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` :

```
sed 's/[^|]*|//' file.txt
```