# Remove all strings before tab (include tab) in a line of text

Tags: sed, grep

A text file (file name: 1.txt):

```
Incoming_Queries_A:     13201096
Incoming_Queries_A6:    946
Incoming_Queries_AAAA:  1288191
Incoming_Queries_ANY:   31280
Incoming_Queries_AXFR:  5
Incoming_Queries_CNAME: 410
Incoming_Queries_DS:    20
Incoming_Queries_MX:    854
Incoming_Queries_NS:    97217
Incoming_Queries_PTR:   1011409
Incoming_Queries_SOA:   5006
Incoming_Queries_SPF:   1
Incoming_Queries_SRV:   3555
Incoming_Queries_TXT:   511
Incoming_Requests_IQUERY:       11
Incoming_Requests_NOTIFY:       1
Incoming_Requests_QUERY:        15640501
Incoming_Requests_STATUS:       1
Incoming_Requests_UPDATE:       5
```

I want to remove all strings before tab (include tab) in a line of text and print the output(example: 13201096 ) to standard out.

Example:

```
# egrep -i "Incoming_Queries_A:" ./1.txt | sed  's/.Incoming_Queries_A:\t//'
```

Output:

```
Incoming_Queries_A:     13201096
```

But I only want to output **13201096**

How to fix it? thanks

Comment: You should use `awk` for column filtering.

Comment: possible duplicate of [awk - how to delete first column with field separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448153/awk-how-to-delete-first-column-with-field-separator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` doesn't automatically handle escaped chars (such as `\t` and `\n`) on bash. You can handle it in two different ways:

- You can replace the `\t` by an actual tab in your expression. To hit a tab in the terminal, you do `Control-V`, then hit the TAB key: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
- (this one seems far more elegant, IMO) you can force sed to interpret your `\t`, by placing a `$` before your substitution string. This way, your command would be like:

  ```
  egrep -i "Incoming_Queries_A:" ./1.txt | sed $'s/Incoming_Queries_A:\t//'
  ```

(I removed that `.` before `Incoming_Queries_A:` - probably a typo/desperate tentative)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only need the second column, you can use cut:

```
cut -f2 file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`you can do this like that:

```
awk '{print $2}' 1.txt
13201096
946
1288191
31280
5
410
20
854
97217
1011409
5006
1
3555
511
11
1
15640501
1
5
```

Or `awk '/Incoming_Queries_A:/ {print $2}' /tmp/t.txt` for get only the line you wanted

Comment: Just curious how a `.` appeared in the second to last line of output?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below GNU sed command,

```
sed -r 's/^.*\t//' file
```

Comment: Your current solution is not very clear, because tabs and spaces don't look different. Also, if there were many columns, you would remove all of them but the last one. I would go for something more general like `sed 's/^[^\t]*\t//' file`. Also, adding some explanation would be useful.

Comment: It worked to me on `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`. I see your update: nice, then it is good to indicate so in your answer.

Comment: @fedorqui your comment here is most complete answer for question in title!