# Is it Possible to Delete "C:\cygwin64\usr\share\" Directory, to Decrease The Cygwin Library Size?

Tags: cygwin

I've the Cygwin Packages Library installed om my system (Win7- x64) at location `C:\Cygwin64\`  .
That directory contains over 185.000 Files ! and its size passed the 5GB this week, Knowing that the packages source directory isn't included .

Now, I want to decrease that size, and of-course I'm going to uninstall some of my packages that I don't need anymore. But first I want to ask about the ability of deleting a specific directory that located in: `C:\cygwin64\usr\share`

(Please, forgive my ignorant, if my question is silly)

While I was trying to figure out the cause of that large files number, I noticed that, this directory specifically, has over than 90.000 File !!

I don't Know what is that directory used for, but would someone please tell me if I can Delete that folder safely, without affecting on the installed packages? - Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for the entirety of the folder, but
[awk uses](http://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/gawk/gawk-4.1.1-1) that folder for
include files, which I would miss

- [delete a column with awk or sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15361632/#26987830)
- [awk - how to delete first column with field separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16448153/#26987888)
- [how to remove the first two columns in a file using shell (awk, sed, whatever)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13446255/#26987784)